# the more optimized way to get data from database in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm working on a news website which on home page I have to show 3 items from each category and there are alike 20 categories. What I have tried:

```
$politicals = News::whereHas('categories', function ($q) {
    $q->where('categories.slug','politics');
})->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->get();

$economical = News::whereHas('categories', function ($q) {
    $q->where('categories.slug','economical');
})->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->get();

$conversation = News::whereHas('categories', function ($q) {
    $q->where('categories.slug','conversation');
})->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->get();

$socialMedia = News::whereHas('categories', function ($q){
    $q->where('categories.slug','socialMedia');
})->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->get();
```

Consider that I have a `manyToMany` relationship on categories and if the number of news goes high like 2000 news the home page I think would be really slow and I think that I cant use `cache` because news change like every 5 or more minutes. So I wanted to know if there is any better way to do some repeatable queries like mine . thanks in advance

Comment: 3x20 is 60 records, not 2000. Besides, [caching](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache) is being supported.

Comment: 2000 news is not high at all. Is you database indexed?

Comment: try whereIn $q->whereIn('categories.slug',['politics','conversation']) and split from PHP code

Comment: you can pass the category slug directly via request or by parameter to the query  or
use switch case instead of every time running full query

Comment: @Nouphal.M And how to take 3 from each category??

Comment: @RushikeshGanesh its in my controller and i am sending the data to view how is that possbile ?

Comment: @MartinZeitler i  say for example after 1 year i get like 1milion news then it would be so heavy

Comment: @pr1nc3 i know it was an example :) consider 2m news for example

Comment: @Farshad Please stop exaggerating a performance problem, where there is none.

Comment: If you database is indexed properly then this is still not a bottleneck. How fast your queries run  is based mostly on your db structure. Based on your question you are worried that you queries will run slow when the data grows big in your tables that's why i am pointing this solution also.

Comment: @pr1nc3 very well then i have to ask a question about how to index it properly then :)\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can write the query like this

```
$news = Category::with(['news' => function($q){
        $q->take(3);
    }])->get();
```

this query will get you all categories and each category with 3 news

you also need to define the relations in the models

in Category.php

```
public function news()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(News::class);
}
```

Comment: Please share more details. How does your approach ensure that the database isn't used as much as in the original code?

Comment: yes right can you please share some detail that what the query would look like with this thing that all the lazy load items are going to be loaded i mean the news items

Comment: it is the same idea in your code, but instead of writing 20 query, each one for category, you can combine them in one @Farshad